# How do I wait a certain amount of time without pausing the whole program? (Discord.py rewrite.)

Tags: python, discord, wait, discord.py

Excuse the bad code, but here it is.

I enter the time I want a user to be muted, I mute the user, and sleep for a certain amount of time, but when I sleep I can't run any commands, so I'm assuming sleeping pauses the whole program, how do I stop that? also please don't come at me with hard programmer man language, i started yesterday, as simple as possible please XD

````
@client.command()
async def chatmute(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, time = 5):
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="-")
    await user.add_roles(role)
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'User has been chat muted.')
    time.sleep(time)
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'Your mute ran out, {user.mention}')**```
````

Answer (score 1):

With asynchronous functions, you can use the `asyncio` library. It is used to write concurrent code.
So, instead of using `time.sleep`, you should use `asyncio.sleep`:

```py
from asyncio import sleep

@client.command()
async def chatmute(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, time = 5):
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="-")
    await user.add_roles(role)
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'User has been chat muted.')
    sleep(time)
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'Your mute ran out, {user.mention}')**
```

**Reference:** [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) documentation